# Scheduling a terminal command or script file to run daily at a specific time Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scheduler, launchd

I want to have my computer set its volume to a specific level every night at 11:45 PM. I'm running OSX 10.11.4. I can set the volume manually through terminal with

```
osascript -e "set Volume 1.7"
```

or as a script with

```
set volume 1.7
```

I want it to be scheduled nightly though. It's hard to find anything online that isn't super outdated. I don't really want to use iCal. From what I've found online, `launchd` is the way to go, but as a noob, I don't know where to start.

I see things about using a .plist in /Library/LaunchAgents. So I found a nifty plist generator [Launched.zerowidth.com](http://launched.zerowidth.com/) but what kind of code do I put in the plist to get the desired effect? I'm also questioning if this is the correct path for this to execute if any user is logged on.

Am I going down the wrong path here? I'm open to any ideas to make this happen, but I don't want to use a 3rd party app that I have to keep open all the time.

Thanks,

Naboo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an OS question (scheduling a task) rather than a programming question. Your question may be better suited for [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Do not use cron, it has been deprecated. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) for scheduling jobs describes how you do this with launchd

Comment: When you say cron has been deprecated, does that mean it no longer works?

Comment: @Cauder `cron` still works on macOS (as of macOS 11 Big Sur 2020). It's fine to use to `cron`. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) says "In OS X, you can run a background job on a timed schedule in two ways: `launchd` jobs and `cron` jobs. (Older approaches, such as `at` jobs and `periodic` jobs are deprecated and should not be used.)"

Answer (score 44):

As @TheDarkKnight points out, cron has been deprecated in favor of launchd.

To use launchd, save the following as `com.example.volume.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.volume</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>sh</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>set volume 1.7</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>23</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>45</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.volume` to start. You can force the task to run immediately via `launchctl start com.example.volume`.

If you prefer to have it run as root, save to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` instead.

Comment: Who knows if it'll be up for the long-term, but here's a nice launchd tutorial - http://www.launchd.info/

Comment: Compared to cron this is hilariously tedious seeming ;-)

Comment: @agathodaimon, Yes, simple is better. But only until you need the feature enhancements. launchd support for sleep mode and more complex time conditions makes it a better solution for many use cases.

Comment: @ikanab Not quite sure all the great features justifies the big file approach, bit okiedokie :)

Comment: I called osascript directly (here, I'm muting, but the idea is the same). 
     `<array>`
      `<string>osascript</string>`
      `<string>-e</string>`
      `<string>set volume output muted true</string>`
      `</array>`

Comment: How difficult can Apple possibly make it to run a script periodically? On Windows, there is a task scheduler, no programming experience required.

Answer (score 32):

Please consider using the cron daemon. It is present in osx by default.

Create script for volume adjusting

```
#!/bin/bash -l
/usr/bin/osascript -e "set Volume 1.7"
```

Then add new line to crontab.

```
crontab -e
```

By default, it will open in the vi(m) editor. But you can adjust the default editor with

```
export EDITOR=/path/to/your/awesome/editor
```

Then add new string to crontab

```
0 20 * * * /path/to/volume/script.sh
```

The given command will run every day at 8 pm.

Please find more crontab examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @Naboo, please mark my answer as right if it was useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As stated in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) *"Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd."*

Comment: No need to create a separate bash script to run an applescript command or script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854193/scheduling-a-terminal-command-or-script-file-to-run-daily-at-a-specific-time-mac/67975800#67975800

Comment: this is dumb, but what does the `-l` flag do please?

Comment: Causes bash to run as though it were a login shell. --I (lowercase "I")
There is a obviously typo

Comment: It still hasn't been dropped in 2024. They even moved it to the M machines. So I guess this is my choice

Answer (score 6):

For a simple one liner, use `cron`:

```sh
# edit your user crontab
crontab -e

# run daily at 20:00 (8:00pm)
0 20 * * * osascript -e "set Volume 1.7"
```

For a longer script, you can save it as an applescript (`.applescript` plain text or `.scpt` binary). Then call it from `cron`:

```sh
# edit your user crontab
crontab -e

# run daily at 20:00 (8:00pm)
0 20 * * * osascript /path/to/setvolume.applescript
```

---

**Pro Tip:**

To avoid the `Terminal.app would like to administer your computer` prompts every time you edit crontab, you can go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access` and add `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`.

---

**Note:**

While [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) says `launchd` is preferred over `cron`, `cron` is still fully supported thus far even though it's been "deprecated" for years. It's fine to use `cron` until it's actually removed (which may be never).

Comment: Don't forget to give Full Disk Access to `Terminal`! See Settings -> Security & Privacy.