# How to run shell script daily in Mac Os X?

Tags: macos

I am using Mac Os x. I have an shell script and i want to run this automatically daily for given time. Is there anyway to do this without using third party tool.

Comment: Dupes a question on superuser - https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854193/scheduling-a-terminal-command-or-script-file-to-run-daily-at-a-specific-time-mac

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes of course, you can use crontab!

Firstly open the terminal, then launch crontab with:

```
crontab -e
```

In some cases you need to specify the editor (es.nano) like this:

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Now you can add your daily script at 3am like this:

```
0  3  *  *  *  sh /path/to/your/file
```

The format is:

```
min  hour  day_of_month  month  day_of_week  your_command
```

After save the cron, you can check the crontab list whit:

```
crontab -l
```

And if you want remove it with:

```
crontab -r
```

Comment: No, I've just used it in HighSierra, what system you use?

Comment: Thanks @Kerberos.  I tried this                                                                  0 14 30 * * sh /Library/Agents/_wrk/OldFilesDelete.sh But nothing happened

Comment: is there anything missing

Comment: @AMNKumari, your cron is triggered only montly, for daily you must add an * at the day_of_month camp.

Comment: Use `env EDITOR=nano crontab -e` instead of `crontab -e`, if you prefer vim you can use vim instead of nano in the command

Comment: @AMNKumari, if you want to start daily at 11:03am you can use: `3  11  *  *  *  sh /yourPath/yourScript.sh`

Comment: i had entered it. so after that how i know its working or not. its not showing any message.

Comment: You can use a test script with `touch asd` that creates a new file. It is normal that it not show nothing after save the crontab.

Comment: @AMNKumari see the edit to show the crontab list and if you want remove it

Comment: After adding the command if you use nano you can use cmd+x and then Y to save, if you use vim you can use  `:wq` to save and quit.

Comment: its saved now. (Y)

Comment: i entered like this but its not run correct time   48 7 * * * sh /Library/Agents/_wrk/OldFilesDelete.sh

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via LaunchDaemons

Just create a file with below syntax and put on /Library/LaunchDaemons/ and save it in .plist

now script will run every 13:30 Hours - you can change time what ever you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>COM.COMPANY.LOGGER</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>YOUR-SCRIPT-LOCATION</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
          <key>Hour</key>
          <integer>13</integer>
          <key>Minute</key>
          <integer>15</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Have you typed your script location on 9th line.
`<string>/User/Desktop/test.sh</string>`