# Why doesn’t this bash script work when scheduled?

Tags: bash, macos, sh, launchd

I have a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /
pwd
ls

cd Users
pwd
ls

cd robl
pwd
ls

cd Documents
pwd
ls
```

When I run it manually via `~/bin/script.sh`, it works as expected.

However, when I make a .plist, schedule it and start it it using `launchctl` like so:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.robl.script
launchctl start com.robl.script
```

It fails. Specifically, it runs as expected until the last `ls`, on which it throws the error

```
ls: .: command not found
```

I think this may be some kind of permission issue since the script works when running manually but not via `launchctl`. Especially because all of the `ls`‘s work and print the contents, except for the last one in the `Documents` folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never used `launchctl` myself but I just read the `man` page for it. Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: I think so. I followed the following post, and it works when I manually run the job using launchctl start, verified since it’s outputting most of the commands https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959004

Comment: I don't see the connection with that post and what you've shown.  `ls: .: command not found` looks like you managed to get supply `ls` as the name to the shell so that it's really `bash` that is saying `.` `command not found` as if `.` is the command to be executed.

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense, but you might be running into trouble with the privacy protections in macOS (your Documents folder is considered a private area). See ["Why do I get "ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted" when I own Desktop?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425519/) and ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear - when I execute the job via ‘launchctl start com.robl.script’, I know the script is executing as expected up until the last ‘ls’ because the rest of the commands are being output as expected. When I execute the job and look at the output file, the contents of all commands except the last ‘ls’ are shown as they should be.